# Is it possible to sign out of xbox console companion and sign back in with c#?

Tags: c#, xbox

I'm trying to make a Alt Switcher made out of C#, I couldn't find out how to Sign Out/Sign In with Xbox Console Companion, is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

I would just make a macro. I am sure there are other ways of doing this, but a macro would be easy and simple.